# Escape a text for javascript from resource bundle

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm setting a javascript variable to a text from a resource bundle:

```
var errorMessage = '<s:text name='base.error'/>';
```

This works correctly as far as the text in the resource bundle doesn't contain a quote (') character.
Do you know how can I encode the text for javascript? I do not have control over the texts in the resource bundle so changing them is not an option.
I was thinking that I can use the method `escapeJavaScript` in `com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextUtils`, but I can't make it work in the jsp.
Thanks

Comment: you need to fix it in resource bundle itself like use `' as \''` and it should work, alternate is to read values in action class and use `<s:property>` tag which has escape attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:property value="getText('base.error')" escapeJavaScript="true" />
```

Comment: is it ? even if struts parses `getText('base.error')`, it will look up for a bean like `parsedValue`

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes(") will not cause your javascript to break when the resource-value contains single quotes(').

```
var errorMessage = "<s:text name='base.error'/>";
```